# Disable garbage collection in C# for debugging?

Tags: c#, debugging, garbage-collection, interop

Is it possible to completely turn off garbage collection in C#?  I'm debugging some hairy managed/native interop memory errors and I'd like to quickly rule out the possibility that GC is freeing native objects that I still need.

Comment: As the GC *never* frees native objects (well, not directly anyway), you can skip this test. How about posting the error and the code which causes it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, GC collects only when object goes out of the scope. Why do you leave objects out of scope when you need them?

Comment: I use SWIG to create C# wrappers around C++ classes.  The C# wrapper deletes the native object when it's collected.  Other C++ objects can acquire native pointers to the wrapped object, which become invalid if C# collects it.  Really not sure why everyone is trying to go off on tangents when the question I asked is so simple and direct.

Comment: @japreiss: Because the question sounds misinformed on its face.  That sounds like an awfully error prone design btw.

Comment: @Ed S. I agree, unfortunately it is beyond my control.  Acquiring grey hairs from it regularly.

Comment: Use fixed statement or GCHandle.Alloc for allocation objects.

Answer (score 8):

That's not possible.

Testing for this kind of bug scenario is done *exactly* the opposite way: you force a garbage collection before or after the interop call.

That's built into the debugger.  It has two managed debugging assistants that can force a GC on an interop transition, [gcManagedToUnmanaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya4zeek2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css) and gcUnmanagedToManaged.  Enable them in your .config file as shown in the linked article.